# refreshing / maunally typing url gives blank page - React router dom 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

all pages links work fine when I click on something to navigate i.e  tag it redirect me to page I want. but on page when I click reload. it gives me blank page.
here are my routers

> react router @6
> MERN stack - reactjs

## index.js

```
<Router> 
  <Header/>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/product/:id" element={<Product />} />
    <Route path="/products/:category" element={<AllProducts />} />
    <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
    <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
    <Route path="/admin" element={<AdminPanel />} />
    <Route path="/auth" element={<Auth />} />
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   
  </Routes>
  <Footer />
</Router>
```

for eg when I click on a button

```
<Link to='/cart' > <Button> go to cart </Button></Link>
```

it redirect me to desire page . and everything works fine.

- but when I reload page . it gives black page. and even If I copy url and paste it in new tab it give blank page.

[check out code on gitHub](https://github.com/napiyo/E-commerce/blob/master/frontEnd/src/index.js)

Comment: On what page you're reloading and could you share some codes from other routes? Even, the best way to inspect this is by sharing code on codesandbox.

Comment: On all pages I’m having this issue.

Comment: Please add your imports in example

Answer (score 0):

use exact keyword with route might be your router is confused in picking the right url:

```
 <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
```

Comment: I have already tried. It’s not working.

Comment: Can you please share codesandbox ?

Comment: https://github.com/napiyo/E-commerce/blob/master/frontEnd/src/index.js

Comment: Code is working fine on my side I have visited profile page, cart page and then refresh them it works fine.

Comment: yes brother. it is working fine when I tried on Firefox, and in incognito. but I'm still having the same issue on my main chrome. I guess it is caused by some extensions.

Comment: can you help me how deal with  Access-Control-Allow-Origin . I'm using some chrome extensions to deal with it. and may I connect with you on linkedIn ?

Comment: Why are you using extensions to deal with Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
As we dont need it for react site. If you are talking about API Call in react side then you need to enable cors in your express app by installing cors package and then you can use app.use(cors()); it will enable cors and your issues will get resolved

Comment: You can view the following package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: yes I have tried this. but still getting issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71207701/cross-origin-request-blocked-node-js-express

Comment: I have your backend code too and its working fine when I hit API call from React App

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242228/discussion-between-narendra-dewasi-and-asad-haroon).

Comment: Please disable your extensions as I think because of them you are facing errors.

Comment: I'm using firefox . it has no extensions. go to any product and try to write review for product . you'll see error.

Comment: I have updated git repo. please check

Comment: First of all you have errors on home page. In BookForSlider component you are reading product in props and assigning product id to the link in bookforslider and you are not passing product in props of BookForSlider component so please pass the product as follows and dont assign Link as Parent to bookForSlider component as you have already attached Link in BookforSlider component:
 <BookForSlider product={{_id:"a"}}/>